# How to match 2 image height in single row with padding in between and keep responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have 2 images which are different in dimension and aspect ratio. I need to put them into the same row and match their heights. There are fixed padding between the photos, let say 25px. the whole thing needs to be responsive, and the width of two images plus the padding is always equal to 100%. How can I do this in CSS and JS / jQuery?

[image]

Comment: Share us your code please

Comment: you might want to checkout something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: do you have a fixed height for the rows? you say, it needs to be responsive ... so the image size shall adjust on screen dimensions... how should the images adjust, if the user views the page in portrait mode. should they be underneath each other or really small but still in the same row?

Comment: I should have explained more clearly :). If screen size smaller than 768px, it will become single column layout. Otherwise it will keep 2 images in a single row. I don't think we can apply a fixed row height here, since the images dimension are unknown. If we want to keep the whole thing 100%, the height and width of the images will changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible with a little bit of playing with HTML/CSS. You need to make the height of the image container fix and set the overflow to hidden. But a major setback is, if your image doesn't fit the ratio of the container then your image will stretch and that is bad.

What you might want to try is Masonry plugin (jQuery) or you can also look into Backstretch jQuery Plugin.

I would strongly suggest you go through the [Masonry Plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

If you don't want to use any Jquery Plugin then, to get the best result, you might have to do a lot of Photoshop to resize the image according to the design.